# Stopping GNU make from printing specific lines

Tags: makefile

GNU make by default prints any lines containing shell commands before those commands 
are issued by the shell.

If I do not want GNU make to print some of these lines , what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@` in front of the lines you don't want printed out:

```
test:
    echo twice
    @echo just once
```

(Use the `-s` switch to suppress all output.)